# Joining digits in binary string

Tags: binary, bit-strings

Given a binary string of length $k \in \mathbb{N}_+$ find a maximum number of digits you can remove by combining adjacent elements into opposite ones (i.e you can combine 2 adjacent $1$s into $0$ or combine 2 adjacent $0$s into $1$).

What I already got: if a string consists only of characters of 1 type then you can reduce it to a string of length $1$ if and only if $k \not\equiv 0 \ \text{(mod 3)}$. Otherwise, it will become a string of length $2$. (if you recursively start adding new digits starting from a one-digit string you can see that $k \ \text{mod 3}$ is an invariant).

Binary strings seem to be simple structures but even after research, I couldn't find any article about that problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand your question... Are we able to iterate the process using what was just combined?  If we have the string 00101010101, we could change the leading two 0's into a 1 to get 1101010101... and then combine those two leading 1's to get 001010101, combining those two zeroes at the start, then combining those two leading 1's at the start, etc... until all we are left with is 0.  Or, are we not allowed to use what we just changed at which point why wouldn't the most be simply from the string 001100110011?

Comment: "*I couldn't find any article about that problem*"  Probably because this seems incredibly simple to the point that it doesn't deserve more than a moments thought and doesn't deserve to be talked about or written down

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It seems more like a programming challenge than a math problem.  And have you tried anything?  What's the answer for, say a string of $32$ $1's$?  If you iterate the process you just get down to a single digit, after all...

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, combining two elements doesn't stop us from using their product again later.

Comment: @lulu It's not a specific problem, but derived from https://stackoverflow.com/q/68857405 (all elements are taken mod 2 and you can only merge adjacent equal elements)

Comment: @JMoravitz There's no need to be rude. The problem is nontrivial, and has a very nice solution leveraging a $\pmod 3$ invariant.

Comment: Here is a reddit post discussing the riddle: https://www.reddit.com/r/mathriddles/comments/sz7zhj/this_actually_has_nothing_to_do_with_projective/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a$ be the number of ones, and $b$ be the number of zeroes. Note that the quantity $a-b\pmod 3$ is invariant, because each move either decreases $a$ by $2$ and increases $b$ by $1$, or vice versa. This means that if $a-b\equiv 0\pmod 3$, there is no hope of reducing the string to a single character. Furthermore, starting from any string which alternates between $0$'s and $1$'s there is no move at all.

I will show that in the case $a-b\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$, and at least one move is available, then you can reduce the string to a single character. Indeed, we just need to show that we can always make a move which leaves another available move. This is OK because any string which contains $00$ will either contain $001$ or $100$, so you can move on those pair of zeroes to get a pair of ones in the result. The only exception to this rule is the case where the string just consists of $n$ zeroes and no ones. If $n\ge 4$, then moving on two zeroes at an end works. $n=3$ cannot happen because that violates $a-b\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$.

By the same logic, you can show that if $a-b\equiv 0\pmod 3$, and there is at least one move available, then you can reduce the string down to two characters.